# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in vue.js http post request

Tags: php, http, vue.js

I am calling a method in my index.php using vue.js http post. While I send the request it shows the error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/project1/public/index.php/signup. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

My vue.js request is

```
this.$http.post('http://localhost/project1/public/index.php/signup', this.dataObject,
function(response) {
  console.log(response)
});
```

In the beginning of index.php, I added

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token ,    Authorization');
signup();
function signup(){
    echo "here";
}
```

Comment: What is the address that you type in browser?

Comment: with postman, when I call localhost/busnet/Prototype/Source/api/public/index.php/signup, it will work. When the same is added in my request, the error comes

Comment: Again, when you want to test your app, you open the browser, and then, what do you type as address?

Comment: [link](localhost:8080)

Comment: Are you sure, that you have served your files, and have php script on different ports? In php scripts it is usually not the case. Maybe you should have `http://localhost:8080/project1/public/index.php/signup` in your address for post?

Comment: My vue.js application and api are running in different ports. vue is on port 8080 and api is on port 80

Comment: OK. Your headers are ok. Actually, only the first one is relevant to the problem. I recently had the same problem, and it was solved by adding this header to response. I would suggest checking if the browser really gets this headers.

Comment: Try calling that same URL (`localhost/busnet/Prototype/Source/api/public/index.php/signu‌​p`) with Postman but use the `OPTIONS` verb and see if you get the headers back.  CORS does an `OPTIONS` request first to see what is allowed.  If everything goes okay with the `OPTIONS` request, the `GET` is allowed.

Comment: Yes..options seems to be the problem.It throws a MethodNotAllowedException, but I have added OPTIONS in Access-Control-Allow-Methods. Then why it happens?

Comment: What http server do you use? Because it may not respond properly to OPTIONS request. Your script may not be used when OPTIONS request comes.